# How do I pass ModelAttribute between Controllers?

Tags: java, spring, modelattribute

I'm trying to create a Home page with 2 functionalities:

1. Login
2. Sign Up

I'm mapping each request to a different controller and trying to get the result back to my `home.jsp`. But I'm having trouble passing only certain specific `ModelAttribute` around, between Controllers. More specifically, i cant get the changed I make to the `ModelMap` and `BindingResult` in one controller to be reflected in others.

I'm sure there's something *basically* wrong with what I'm doing. Please help.

There are 2 forms in my `home.jsp`. One for Login:

```
<form:form name="loginForm" modelAttribute="loginUser" action="login" method="post">

    Email: <form:input name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" value="" path="email"/>
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
    <br/>

    password: <form:password name="loginPassword" Id="loginPassword" value="" path="password" />
    <form:errors path="password" />
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" id="id_login" value="Login">

</form:form>
```

and the other one for Sign Up:

```
<form:form name="SignUpForm" modelAttribute="signUpUser" action="signup" method="post">

    Full Name: <form:input name="name" id="name" value=""   path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
    <br/>

    Email: <form:input name="signupEmail" id="signupEmail" value="" path="email"/>
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
    <br/>

    password: <form:password name="signUpPassword" Id="signUpPassword" value="" path="password" />
    <form:errors path="password" />

    <input type="submit" id="id_signUp" value="Sign Up">

</form:form>
```

I have 3 controllers: `HomeController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String showHome(ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute("loginUser") User loginUser,
        BindingResult loginResult,
        @ModelAttribute("signUpUser") User signUpUser,
        BindingResult signUpResult) {
    return "home";
}
```

`AuthenticationController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(@ModelAttribute("loginUser") User user,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    loginFormValidator.validate(user, result);

    if(Errors in `result`)
        return "forward:/home";

    // Authentication Logic
    request.getSession().setAttribute("s_user_obj", some_variable);
    return "forward:/home";

}
```

and `ProfileController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public String signUpUser(@ModelAttribute("signUpUser") User user,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
// Do stuff related to Sign Up
// Forward to home.jsp
    }
```

When the request is forwarded to `/home`, I'm getting same values in both `loginUser` and `signUpUser`. Worse, there are no errors i.e. the `result` variable is not reflecting the ones in the previous controllers.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, this is a newbie's attempt at it. Please advice.

Comment: so in showHome(), you want to access the value of the session attribute `s_user_obj`? Then why not just access the Session object? I don't think `@ModelAttribute` works the way you think it does http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain the anomaly (Why are both the `ModelAttribute`s getting populated with the same values?)
This being something almost *every* web-app does, isn't there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you have methods annotated with @ModelAttribute also? What is the value of the `User` object - is it the result of invoking a default constructor on User?

Comment: No, I don't have any methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. Whatever I have, I've posted here.

`User` is a typical value object with several fields and corresponding getters and setters

Comment: @mattb If you were to implement the same functionality, how would you go about it? I'm open to changing the code completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that I see here is the way `@ModelAttribute("loginUser")` and `@ModelAttribute("signUpUser")` is interpreted for methods by Spring - here is some reference - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

The arguments are retrieved from the model(and instantiated if necessary), but the problem part is that they are repopulated based on the request parameters, which would end up populating both your attributes the same way. The only workaround that I can think of is to explicitly retrieve the model attributes yourself in your method:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String showHome(ModelMap model) {
    model.get("loginUser");...
    model.get("signUpUser");...
    return "home";
}
```

**Update**

Based on your comments, let me recommend an alternate flow and a more explicit flow:

Have a method which sets both your loginUser and signUpUser model attributes this way:

```
private void populateAttributes(Model model, User loginUser, User signupUser){
    if (loginUser==null) loginUser = new User();
    if (singupUser==null) singupUser = new User();
    model.addAttribute("loginUser", loginUser);
    model.addAttribute("signupUser", signupUser);
}
```

Now in your login flow:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(User user,
    BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) {

loginFormValidator.validate(user, result);

if(Errors in `result`)
    populateAttributes(user, null);
    return "home";

// Authentication Logic
request.getSession().setAttribute("s_user_obj", some_variable);
populateAttributes(model, user, null);
return "home";
```

}

Similar flow in your signup:

```
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public String signUpUser(User user,
    BindingResult result, Model model) {
    populateAttributes(model, null, user);
    return "home"
}
```

and showHome:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String showHome(Model model,) {
    populateAttributes(model, null, null);
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: I cant find a `getAttribute()` function in `ModelMap` class.

Comment: sorry, it should be `model.get(..)`

Comment: (And it required a cast to `User` too) But how does that solve anything? It's a `NullPointerException` the first time I load the view. Besides, how can the errors be carried over to the `HomeController` if you do this?

Comment: Binding related errors should get carried over cleanly, did not understand why a NullPointerException first time around, can you please clarify

Comment: Because the first time you call `showHome()` method in the `HomeController.java`, they're not initialized. They would've been, had we used `@ModelAttribute` annotation.
NB: The Binding errors dont get to the next controller. And there's this issue with the `ModelAttribute`s having the same value. Do you have a solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, yes I think I finally understand your issue much better now - I have added an updated answer, which makes things a little more explicit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't work. `if (loginUser==null)` never works since `loginUser` is instantiated every time the method `showHome` is called.
What exactly do you mean by `populateAttributes`?